# .net html to pdf multiple column

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html-to-pdf

I'm looking for a .NET library that supports CSS3 multiple columns, like in the image. The green arrow is the correct flow, red is the wrong: [image: Img1]

I tried a lot of components, but they all create pdfs with the red flow. Only http://www.princexml.com/samples/ works but it's very very expensive.
I also tried wkhtmltopdf but there is probably a CSS3 column property bug, because no column was generated:  [image: Img2]

Someone can help me to achieve Img1 green arrow flow?
Thanks

Comment: DocRaptor uses the Prince library, but with a different (much cheaper upfront) pricing model. All other tools that are likely to do this (pdfReactor, etc) are going to be priced similarly to Prince.

Comment: yes, it's also too expensive. i need to create around 80k pdf per month.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at pdfSharp (http://www.pdfsharp.net)

You will probably need to create the html to pdf yourself by adding the content to a new PDF document.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate a PDF from a view you can use Rotativa. See this [link](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa). Rotativa will get your view and render into a PDF, considering your css rules.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, i tried but doesn't. Same problem of Img2. I think becaouse it use wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: So try SelectPdf, it doesn't use wkhtmltopdf. http://selectpdf.com/demo/

Comment: I've already tested it. It's follow red flow not green.
Green flow look like impossible to archive with a low budget.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any cheap .net library, but i found a very good alternative developed in Python http://weasyprint.org/. Works very well and archive all of my needs (column support, header and footer, @page etc..). The only negative thing is that i need to configure a linux small server to expose api for convert html to pdf width weasyprint.
At the moment a think is a good compromise.